# Dispatcher.BeginInvoke Action with Parameters

Tags: c#, dispatcher

I'm using a Dispatcher to update my UI before I handle some resiszing.
The Problem ist the part of BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriorty, **new ACTION**) is where I am stuck.
I want to call a method **with** Parameters and I don"t know why.

Thats my current Dispatcher:

```
void s_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action(test));

}
```

And this is my method i am calling:

```
public void test()
{
    foreach (Structures s in ((TreeView)this.cont.Children[0]).Items)
        s.updateRelationLines(this.Data, this.cont.ColumnDefinitions[1]);
}
```

I just want to replace `this.Data` and `this.cont.Columndefinitions[1]` with Parameters.

Comment: How do you expect the value of the parameters to be set?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a lambda expression for this:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, 
    new Action(() => test(param1, param2)));
```

This basically creates an anonymous method

```
void myMethod() {
    test(param1, param2);
}
```

and invokes this method through the dispatcher. Some compiler magic ensures that param1 and param2 are available to this method, even if they are only in the scope of your `s_SizeChanged` method. More details on this can be found here:

- [Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Comment: One thing to be aware of with this approach is if param1 or param2 are changed before test is called, then test will get the new values of param1/param2 not the old value.

Comment: @CodeNaked, that bug was fixed in C# 5.

Comment: @l33t: You probably mean the `foreach` issue. In general, CodeNaked's statement still holds: `param1 = 1; BeginInvoke(...); param1 = 2` might still use the new value of param1.

Comment: I was searching all over for a simple way to disable a button while a process ran. All I found were convoluted & ridiculous answers. This was perfect!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action<Type1, Type2>(test), type1, type2);
```

With a callback like:

```
public void test(Type1 type1, Type2 type2) {
        foreach (Structures s in ((TreeView)this.cont.Children[0]).Items)
            s.updateRelationLines(type1, type2);
    }
```